# Left and right index in the exponent

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

What is the difference between $$\chi$$ from the left and from the right [here](https://shelah.logic.at/v1/nonstructure/IV.pdf) on the page $3$, item $(c)$:

[image: ]]

Comment: I think it is a notation: so the weird notation is equivalent to e.g. for the left : $\lambda$ such $\lambda >\chi$

Comment: @Gae.S.yes i corrected it

Comment: @EDX Sorry could you be please more specific about what is the difference between left and right $\chi$ ? I didn't catch you.

Answer (score 0):

The author writes ' $\lambda < \chi $, $\chi$ regular ' case at page 2. That means that the work it presents will be aware of the distinction when $\lambda > \chi $ or when $\lambda \leq \chi$. So in your equality, the left exponent is just there to indicate whether $\lambda$ is in the case of $ \lambda \leq \chi$ or $\lambda > \chi$.

It is important to put it at right not to be confuse with $\lambda^\chi$ that denote the set of applications of $\chi$ to $\lambda$.

Comment: What are **set of applications of $\chi$ to $\lambda$** ?

Comment: It the set that contains all applications which at some elements of $\chi$ associate elements of $\lambda$  possible because $\chi $ and $\lambda$ are sets and $\leq$ is the comparision law on sets (included in).